# How to do a spinner wheel in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make a UI element that you can drag and it rotates and when you stop, if it has enough force, it will start spinning in the direction it was being dragged and then stop. I managed to get some code but I cannot make the last part, which is letting go and make the wheel spin in the way it was dragged.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class TouchControl : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler
{
    private Vector2 initialPosition;
    private float angleOffset;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData){
        RectTransform rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        initialPosition = rectTransform.position;
        Vector2 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

        Vector2 offset = mousePosition - initialPosition;
        angleOffset = Mathf.Atan2(offset.y, offset.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - rectTransform.eulerAngles.z;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData){
        RectTransform rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        Vector2 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

        Vector2 offset = mousePosition - initialPosition;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(offset.y, offset.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - angleOffset;
        rectTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, angle);
    }
}
```

And is there any way to control the duration of the spin and the speed it will start rotating? I am trying to achieve an effect similar to this: https://spinthewheel.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply while dragging keep track of the angular speed

```
float previousAngle;
float angularVelocity; // in angle per second

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    var rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    var mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

    Vector2 offset = mousePosition - initialPosition;
    var angle = Mathf.Atan2(offset.y, offset.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - angleOffset;

    rectTransform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, angle);

    angularVelocity = (angle - previousAngle) / Time.deltaTime;

    previousAngle = angle;
}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    // use angularVelocity here
    // e.g. either apply to a rigid body or run a routine etc
}
```